# in MVC 4 how to render one of view elements as XML text?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC 4 application I trying to build a standard Details view but one of the field is an XML text and I wanted to leave as such on the page. I spend already a couple of hours trying but the best I could do it displays content of XML removing tags.

```
div class="display-label">
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.stringElement)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.stringElement)
</div>

<div class="display-label">
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.xmlElement)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @MvcHtmlString.Create(ViewBag.xmlElement)
</div>
```

First field is displayed as expected while second one displays all the content but all the tags, end-of-lines in xmlElement string are lost. I saw a reference if whole page was xml I could use text/xml as the page type but this is just one filed in the view. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your view code as below:

If xmlElement is not encoded:

```
 <div class="display-field">
      @MvcHtmlString.Create(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(ViewBag.xmlElement).Replace("\n", "<br/>"))
 </div>
```

If xmlElement is encoded:

```
  <div class="display-field">
      @MvcHtmlString.Create(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(ViewBag.xmlElement).Replace("\n", "<br/>"))
 </div>
```

This will treat your xml as text.

**Updated answer based on the comments**

You can replace the end of the lines with `<br/>` tag. That will solve your problem without any external libraries

Comment: Awesome, it now shows all of tags. But I all of end-of-line are gone so it now looks like one long string. Any chance I can either keep original <eol>s or apply any "xml beautifier" that shows proper idents?

Comment: You can try using something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094180/indentation-and-new-line-command-for-xmlwriter-in-c-sharp or use markdown

Comment: You can use http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/ or You can try some of these packages for markdown http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=markdown

Comment: You steered me in the right direction, so I am accepting the answer. Final version was to format my string as recommended in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744320/c-sharp-xmlelement-outerxml-in-a-single-line-rather-than-format/ and then simply enclose your solution in <pre> @MvcHtmlString.Create(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(ViewBag.xmlElement)) </pre>